# Capture data from remote python script .

Tags: python, json, return, paramiko

I have a remote python script which I call from my local system using another python script.

I want to capture the dict type object returned by the remote script how do I do that .

Sample remote :

`data={}
data=<some data>
return(data)`

How do I capture this data object on my local script , I am using paramiko  module to connect to remote script .

Or should I use something else in place of return , like dumping a json or something .

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your code that creates data dict into some function

```
def generate_data():
    data={}
    data=<some data>
    return(data)
```

In your local script just import your remote script

```
import remote
```

Then call the function

```
local_data = remote.generate_data()
```

Hope this helps!